# jQuery Children length of an ol

Tags: jquery, html, children

I am trying to count the child elements of an OL

**jQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#my_select").change(function(){
    alert($("#ol3").children.length);
                                     });});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ol id="ol1">
    <li class="2">Location 1-1</li>
</ol>

<ol id="ol2">
    <li class="15">Location 2-1</li>
    <li class="20">Location 2-2</li>
</ol>

<ol id="ol3">
    <li class="17">Location 3-1</li>
    <li class="16">Location 3-2</li>
    <li class="14">Location 3-3</li>
</ol>
```

I always get the number 2 no matter how many li are there under the ol.

Know what's going on..?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try

```
$("#ol3").children().length \\ you missed () in children...
```

when you do `$("#ol3").children.length` it returns the number of arguments in the `.children()` function...

try alerting `$("#ol3").children` and you will get this...

```
function (d,f){var e=c.map(this,b,d);eb.test(a)||(f=d);if(f&&typeof f==="string")e=c.filter(f,e);e=this.length>1?c.unique(e):e;if((this.length>1||gb.test(f))&&fb.test(a))e=e.reverse();return this.pushStack(e,a,R.call(arguments).join(","))}
```

where `d` and `f` are the two arguments... that's why you are always getting 2 in your code when you alert..

Comment: :) Thanks! that was fairly simple.

Answer (score 3):

Try `children()` instead of `children`.

For a belt-and-suspenders approach, try `children('li')`.

Comment: :) Thanks! that was fairly simple.

Comment: I like the saying "belt-and-suspenders"

Answer (score 2):

you can also use .size() instead of .length()

either one works, though .length() is supposedly faster.